# I need insert bangla language to Mysql database in Java desktop application

Tags: mysql

I have developed a desktop application using java and mysql database. I need insert bangla language to Mysql database. How do i do this with java and mysql ?
I have already set mysql database  utf8_general_ci. In jframe used custom font Rupali.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved now. Need to added extra line like that
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

```
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/ovi?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8";//getting url
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","EasyTech@.");//create connection
```